# ASP.NET Core project load time

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET core / MVC Core application that I'm currently working on however when I first load the project into Visual Studio it is taking ages to load (20 minutes).

I'm not exactly sure what is causing the extended load time, but its not Visual Studio itself as other projects load a lot quicker, I'm pretty certain its something with this individual project as it used to work fine, and I've tried it on another laptop and it also takes its time there.

I've also tried starting Visual Studio using the /SafeMode switch but that has made no difference.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Below is a copy of my project.json in case someone can identify a potential issue with it

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.9.1"
  },

  "userSecretsId": "SP2017-5731e8a3-a3ec-4a25-bcb5-asdf2432hjk232",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.6-IR31",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "SendGrid.Core": "1.0.0",
    "SendGrid.NetCore": "1.0.0-rtm-00002"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "Areas/**/*.cshtml",
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.production.json",
      "web.config",
      "project.json"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

**EDIT 12/Jan/17 00:30 GMT:**

- A new simple ASP.NET CORE MVC site opens up nice and quickly
- I am running **Visual Studio 2015 Update 3**
- I am running it on a **Surface Pro 4 i7/16GB/512GB SSD**
- I have run Visual Studio in safe mode (devenv.exe /SafeMode which disables extensions including ReSharper, no increase in load time)
- The issue predates me adding in the SendGrid dependency so its nothing to do with that.
- I have now updated to the latest tooling available (dotnet-win-x64.1.1.0.exe)

I should also mention that I have done the old favourite of turning it off and back on again!

Here is an updated copy of my project.json file

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.9.1"
  },

  "userSecretsId": "SP2017-5731e8a3-a3ec-4a25-bcb5-asdf2432hjk232",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "SendGrid.Core": "1.0.0",
    "SendGrid.NetCore": "1.0.0-rtm-00002",
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-64": {} 
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "Areas/**/*.cshtml",
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.production.json",
      "web.config",
      "project.json"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

I think I might of figured out the cause, but not how to resolve it.

I vaguely remember getting the issue after adding some bower dependencies, is it possible that this could be the cause (I have tried removing all the bower dependencies

My bower.json file currently looks like

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "jquery": "2.2.0",
    "jquery-validation": "1.14.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.6",
    "font-awesome": "4.6.1",
    "admin-lte": "*",
    "material-design-icons": "2.2.3",
    "startbootstrap-creative": "3.3.7"
  }
}
```

I have just added that into my new templated solution and the package restore is taking its time. So I'm wondering if Visual Studio calls the bower restore as part of opening the solution?

Comment: Maybe this isn't a solution but more like a suggestion, you can ignore it. ButI think you might want to buy a SSD drive. I found it's way better performance improvement

Comment: Did you try to run `dotnet build` in a console ?

Comment: @HungCao it is already on an SSD Drive, on a surface pro 4 config with an i7 processor and 16GB ram.

Comment: @Kalten it's not the build taking its time, the build runs fine and quick in both VS and console (the output says build completed in 00:00:09.8916456) it is actually the file->open solution which is taking 20 minutes to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the culprit is actually in the bower dependencies and was

```
"material-design-icons": "2.2.3"
```

After removing this from my bower.json file (and deleting it from the corresponding wwwroot/lib folder), my solution now loads up in around 10-15 seconds (much quicker than 20 minutes).

Out of interest I created a new (non-VS / asp.net core folder), ran **bower cache clear** and then **bower.init**, then ran **bower install material-design-icons**, which took about 10 minutes just to install this 1 package/dependency

Turns out that this package is 43.7MB (81.5MB on disk), and it isn't my internet speed (16ms ping, 104.5Mbps download, 6.3Mbps upload)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion that may work.

I would recommend updating .netcore to 1.1 because there were many issues with 1.0
By running this in your nuget console Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.App

Another issue could be that you are loading a dependency that is failing or not working correctly.

For instance it might be loading your send grid and send grid is very slow and that may be why.

Try to run a very simple app without any dependency's and see if you get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Resharper, try suspending it from VS options menu and see what happens. I am also experiencing longer load times of asp.net core projects with Resharper active. With suspended Resharper, solution loads fast enough

Comment: I've run devenv.exe /SafeMode which disables ReSharper - no increase of speed on application opening

Answer (score 0):

Try these update if those are not latest ones

1. Update your `visual studio` to latest `Visual Studio Update 3`
2. Update your `Visual Studio 2015 Tools` to latest current Visual
       `Studio 2015 Tools (Preview 2)`
3. Update your `.NET Core` to latest current `.NET Core 1.1 SDK`

Then update your project to use latest `.Net Core SDK` as describe [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/) 
and also update all packages from `nuget` as well.

Comment: I've already got VS 2015 update 3 installed, and I have tried your suggestion of upgrading to the latest tooling available, and the project is still taking its time.

Comment: Remove all reference from tools section from `project.json` and try.

Comment: removing references to the tools doesn't make any difference, removing all of the bower dependencies and the wwwroot/lib folder however does make it start up in a more timely manner, however I'm not convinced that this is a solution